# PHP" How to include '-' only when variable exist?

Tags: php

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/'.$type.$q.'number-'.$L.','.$country.'.html
```

If either `$type` or `$q` exist include `-` after them, example:

```
$type = 1
$q = 2
http://www.example.com/1-2-number-fl,us.html
```

but when for example when `$type` not exist to be:

```
http://www.example.com/2-number-fl,us.html
```

UPDATE: How if **$type = 1-** or **$q = 1-** then your could should prevent this to happen: **http://www.example.com/1--2--number-fl,us.html**

Comment: Use the `implode()` function and wrap the variables into an array

Comment: Could you please do for this example, as an answer?

Comment: using trim function could prevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the variables are set and they are not null. Add '-' to each variable.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/'.$type.$q.'number-'.$L.','.$country.'.html';
// declare a variable
$result = '';
// check for the variable type and add '-'
if(isset($type) && ($type!='')){
    $result=trim($type,'-').'-';
}
// check for the variable q and add '-'
if(isset($q) && ($q!='')){
$result.=trim($q,'-').'-';
}

$url = 'http://www.example.com/'.$result.'number-'.$L.','.$country.'.html';
```

Comment: How if **$type = 1-** then your could should prevent this happen: **http://www.example.com/1--2-number-fl,us.html**

Comment: you can use trim function to prevent this. $result=trim($type,'-').'-';

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
if(isset($type)) { $array[] = $type; }
if(isset($q))    { $array[] = $q;    }
$array[] = 'number';
if(isset($L))    { $array[] = $L;    }

$url = "http://www.example.com/".implode('-', $array).",$country.html";
```

- Check if the variables are set with `isset()`
- If so, add them to an array
- Since `number` is a fixed string that you want, add it to the array
- `implode()` the array joining with `-` to use in the URL

You could replace `isset()` with `!empty()` but `0` is considered empty so it would not be usable in the URL.

Comment: Adding a few comments to clarify what you added may be beneficial to OP and others reading it.

Comment: How if **$type = 1-** then your could should prevent this happen: **http://www.example.com/1--2-number-fl,us.html**

Answer (score 0):

Use isset() if both exists then build the string

```
if (isset($type, $q)) {
  $result = $type .'-'. $q;
{
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but it's not enough to use isset() here as an empty string in PHP will still come back as true. This could cause $result to be '-2'
You should use empty() instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to check that $type and $q are not empty -- it's not enough to simply check that they are set. You also need to cover the case where the values are the integer 0 as PHP considers 0 to be an empty string, which causes empty( 0 ) to return true.

You could go with something like this:

```
if ( ((int) $type !== 0 && !empty( $type )) && ((int) $q !== 0 && !empty( $q ))) {
    $result = $type . '-' . $q;
}
elsif ((int) $type !== 0 && !empty( $type )){
    $result = $type;
}
else {
    $result = $q;
}

$url = "http://www.example.com/{$result}-number-{$L}{$country}.html";
```

Answer (score -1):

check isset()

```
if(isset($type))
    http://www.example.com/1-2-number-fl,us.html
else
    http://www.example.com/2-number-fl,us.html
```